# Платформонезависимое асинхронное выполнение задачи

Tags: java, android, асинхронность

Есть ли "родное" платформонезависимое решение для асинхронного выпонения задач? Например, на ПК это `SwingWorker`, на Android это `AsyncTask`.

**Update 0**

Вопрос был заморожен из-за непонятности; приношу свои извинения за кривой слог, сейчас попытаюсь объяснить:
Помогите, пожалуйтса, найти кросс-платформенный аналог Android'овского `AsyncTask`, чтобы там были методы типa `onPreExecute`, `doInBackground`, `onPostExecute` и чтобы этот аналог одинаково работал и на Windows/Linux,  и на Android. Искал в гугле - находил всякие `SwingWorker`'ы, но они зависят от платформы. Пытался перенести исходники `AsyncTask`, но там опять же привязка к платформе из-за классов `Handler` и ему подобных.

Будет ли этот аналог `AsyncTask`'a в виде библиотеки или встроенное решение - значения не имеет.

**Update 1**

О'кей, в результате мозгового штурма задача теперь ещё более упростилась. Нужен кроссплатформенный способ вызвать метод из другого потока в рамках UI(главного)-потока. То есть, например, при запуске программы загружается интерфейс и происходит какая-нибудь анимация, и в другом потоке начинается работа с сетью. После выполнения работы с сетью требуется выполнить метод в UI-потоке, например, чтобы поменять текст на кнопке. Как это можно правильно реализовать *одним* кодом, чтобы работало и на ПК, и на Android?

Comment: Не совсем понял вопроса...вы хотите один код для асинхронный задачи написать, и чтобы он работал на всех платформах? причем, и на ПК, и на мобилках?

Comment: А [`Future<T>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) и всякое вокруг него вас не устраивает?

Comment: Можно с классом Thread и синхронизацией написать свой велосипед. Возможно он уже есть на github.

Comment: "_чтобы этот аналог одинаково работал_" — хм. _Совсем_ одинаково наверное не получится. Например, если на одной платформе последовательные задания выполняются в _одном и том же потоке_, а на другой — нет, это считается «неодинаково»?

Comment: @Vlad, если использовать Future и его окружение, то в сторону каких методов стоит начать копать? Если что, то я обновил вопрос.  hardsky, на гитхаб полез в первую очередь, к своему удивлению нашёл только одно решение (ссылку уже потерял), но при детальном рассмотре там снова оказалась зависимость от платформы.

Comment: А вам не проще отказаться от единного решения?? Если это не критичное требование - сделайте классы отдельно работающие на нужных вам платформах и обращайтесь через wrapper

Comment: @Toly, я хочу реализовать единое решение как часть своего эксперимента. Я разделяю программу на 2 части - "Ядро" и "Интерфейс", где "Ядро" - единый кросс-платформенный код, а подгонять под каждую платформу нужно будет только "Интерфейс".

Comment: То, что вы хотите сделать как раз нужно отнести к интерфейсу. Вы же говорите про UI интерфейс, который в фоне/паралелльно (называйте как хотите) делает запросы. Ядром же будут различные сущности и их методы.

Answer (score 1):

Обычно такая проблема решается паттерном bridge. Заводится отдельный класс - абстрактная реализация асинхронного выполнения задач. И под каждую платформу заводится его конкретная реализация. Также делается базовый класс для, собственно, асинхронной задачи - задачей которого будет найти правильную реализацию и предоставить своим потомкам доступ к ней. Заодно такая схема пригодится в случае, к примеру, перехода на SWT.

Здесь я вижу две проблемы. Проблема первая - сделать так, чтобы код, в котором есть упоминания `SwingWorker`, компилировался под Андроид (и наоборот). Вероятно, для этого надо будет выделить отдельные субпроекты - "реализация моста для Андроида" и "реализация моста для десктопа", компилируемые только для тех платформ, которые их поддерживают. У вас же все равно должны быть отдельные цепочки компиляции для Андроида и для десктопа?

Проблема номер два - выбор нужной реализации. Тут можно предоставить пользователю право (ну, или необходимость) выбрать нужную реализацию при старте. Или же можно воспользоваться тем фактом, что на каждой платформе будет пока что ровно одна реализация - и попросту разместить их под одним именем. В принципе, в таком случае не требуется даже паттерна и отдельной иерархии - но SWT в такую схему уже не включить.

Comment: private static final boolean isMobile = false;

// ...
if (isMobile) {
  // This is removed at compile time
}

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1813853/ifdef-ifndef-in-java

Comment: @DeKaNszn, может быть, устройство лучше проверять [так](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=kvGPXshv)?

Comment: @SuperCreeper в вашем случае компилятор всегда будет оставлять только else. этот "хак" работает на том, что компилятор выкидывает те куски кода, в которые никогда не попадет управление

Answer (score 1):

посмотрите в качестве примера в сторону rxJava в связке с rxAndroid.
Поясню на куске кода.

```
final Subscription subscription =
          createObservable() //создали Observable                                                  
          .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread()) //тут указывается поток, в котором буду выполены основние действия
          .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()) //тут указывается поток, в котором будет выполнена обраотка результата. аналог onPostExecute()
          .subscribe(subscriber); //обработчик результата. в данном случае выполнится в основном потоке(UI)
```

В примере используется класс, явно заточенный под андроид.
К чему это. Думаю что один код в данном случае не получится написать полностью платформонезависимо. Но сократить трудозатраты, думаю можно. Т.е. вы пишете реализацию для обработки в основном потоке отдельно для каждой платформы и выносите из ядра. Платформ не так много.
Думаю библиотка rxJava сделана для таких целей, и там как раз таки нет платформонезависимого обработчика для UI потока.

Если я ошибаюсь, то с удовольствием прочту опровержение. Тема интересна.

Answer (score 0):

К сожалению я пишу на джаве только под андроид не и не знаю, как это работает на других платформах.

1. Самый очевидный вариант решения: написать класс обертку, который в под андроид будет вызывать AsyncTask, а под ПК - SwingWorker, благо функционал тот же и, насколько я могу судить, должен работать так же. Чем вас не утраивает этот вариант?
2. По идее ничего не мешает реализовать тот же класс в ручную. Берешь чистый класс, пишешь функцию onPreExecute(), которую вызываешь сразу после execute(); , потом создаешь новый поток из которого вызывашь doInBackground() своего класса. onPostExecute() и onProgress() вызываешь в UI. В теории должно работать. Реализовать на практике, к сожалению, нет времени.